# java - removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) not working

Tags: java, lru

When i am using `removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest)` to implement LRU cache `removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest)` does not work.

Expected Output= 1,-1,2
Actual output = 1,1,2

Here set method puts entry , get retrieves entry if its there , else return -1:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class LRUCache extends LinkedHashMap {
  int capacity;
  LinkedHashMap map = new LinkedHashMap(capacity ,1.1f,true);

  public LRUCache(int capacity) {
    this.capacity = capacity;
  }

  public int get(int key) {
    if(map.containsKey(key)) {
      return (int) map.get(key);
    }
    return -1;
  }

  public void set(int key, int value) {
    map.put(key,value);
  }

  protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) {
    return map.size()>capacity;
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    LRUCache lru=new LRUCache(1);
    int temp; 

    lru.set(2,1);
    temp=lru.get(2);
    System.out.println(temp);

    lru.set(3,2);
    temp=lru.get(2);
    System.out.println(temp);

    temp=lru.get(3);
    System.out.println(temp);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `removeEldestEntry` is never used. In order for your `removeEldestEntry` to be used, your class must extend `LinkedHashMap` and you should override `LinkedHashMap`'s `removeEldestEntry`.

If you are using a `LinkedHashMap` for your cache, it will use the default implementation of `removeEldestEntry`, which is :

```
protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K,V> eldest) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @NEWUSER You shouldn't use the `map` variable if you are extending `LinkedHashMap`. Replace `map.put(key,value);` with `put(key,value);`, `map.size()` with `size()` and so on.